# how to idividually append directive to div in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

HTML:

```
<div ng-app = "myApp" ng-controller = "someController as Ctrl">

<div class = "clickme" ng-repeat = "elems in Ctrl.elem" ng-click ="click()">
    {{elems.title}}
    click me
    <div id="container">
    </div>
</div>
```

angularjs

```
var Elems = [{title : "1"},
         {title : "2"},
         {title : "3"}];

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('someController', function($scope) {
    var self = this;
    self.elem = Elems;
    $scope.click = function(){
        //append directive <test-Input></test-Input>
    };

});

myApp.directive('testInput',function(){
     return {
          restrict: 'E',
          replace: false,
          transclude: false,
          template: '<div>asdasdasdasd</div>',
          controller: function($scope) {

         }
      };
});
```

how to append directive to individual div when it clicked? I know it will be very easy with Jquery but it's hard to do in angular way.

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to do it this way, one of Angulars advantages is that you do not have to deal with changing the HTML yourself, but use data-binding and templates instead, establishing an MVC-pattern. You are still thinking in jQuery ;-)

Change only your data on click and use `ng-repeat` to make angular append your template for you.

P.S.: Why do you use `$scope` in your controller? You are using `controller as`-sntax (which is good), you can simply bind the `click()`-funciton to the controller instead of `$scope`

Comment: oh I missed that $scope thing It's mixed with another one thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
var modalElementTemplate = angular.element(Your template);
var linkFn = $compile(modalElementTemplate);
var modalElement = linkFn($scope);
$("#WheretoAppend").append(modalElement);
```

Comment: This is really not the way you should write angular code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a huge DOM alteration put the testInput directive in the ngRepeat loop and add a check at the top of the directive whether the div container has been clicked or not (need scope isolation).